# How can I avoid an UnauthorizedAccessException when clicking on links in a webbrowser control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, exception, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I've created a small web bot to click links on webpages however I've come across a small problem.  Currently, on some select sites, when I try to click on the link I get an Access Exception.  I've tried to do some research on these but came across nothing relating to my issue - most of them were issues with iFrame, which doesn't apply to me as the websites I'm using doesn't have any.  What could be preventing me from clicking on links on some websites and not others?  What could I do to get around this?

```
For j = 0 To WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.all.length - 1
    HTMLElementMain = WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.all.item(j)
    If Not HTMLElementMain Is Nothing Then
        If StrComp(HTMLElementMain.TagName, "a", CompareMethod.Text) = 0 Then
            If HTMLElementMain.href <> Nothing Then
                HTMLElementHrefStr = HTMLElementMain.href
                HTMLElementMain.Click()
            End if
        End if
    End if
Next
```

The Trace of the error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
  Message="Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
       at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.VBBinder.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Type objType, IReflect objIReflect, Object target, Object[] args, String[] namedParameters)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateCall(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
       at YTAA.YTAA.btnBegin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at YTAA.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: What exactly throws 'Access Exception'? Is it an exception at all, or maybe you mean the Http 401 status code?

Comment: I've uploaded the trace for the error I'm getting for your convenience.  Perhaps my eyes aren't quite seeing what's wrong :)

Comment: The exception is from the DOM. Is HTMLElementHrefStr a script function? Is the link targeting a new frame or _black?

Comment: HTMLElementHrefStr is only a variable of type String.  No further functions are being called in the block of code there.  I will research DOM